# object not found - copy excel range from one sheet to other

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim cel As Range, lRow As Long

    'next line determines the last row in column 1 (A), of the first Worksheet
    lRow = Worksheets("Delta").UsedRange.Columns(5).Rows.Count

    'iterate over every cell in the UsedRange 
    For Each cel In Worksheets("Delta").Range("E10:E" & lRow)

        'cel represents the current cell
        'being processed in this iteration of the loop

        'Len() determines number of characters in the cell
        If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then

            'if cel is not empty, copy the value to the cell range (D1,D2,D3...) mentioned

            Sheets("Traceability").Select
            Traceability.Range("D3:D100").Select = cel.Value2    '--->Object not defined

        End If

    Next    'move on the next (lower) cell in column 1

End Sub
```

For copying a range of data I am facing an error of object not defined. Is my method to copy cell values correct ?

Comment: What is `Traceability`? Is that the codename of `Sheets("Traceability")`?  `Traceability.Range("D3:D100").Select = cel.Value2`is wrong. It should be `Traceability.Range("D3:D100") = cel.Value2` but that is only correct if `Traceability` is your worksheet.

Comment: `Range("E10:E100" & lRow)` is probably not the range you want to loop on... Maybe you mean `Range("E10:E" & lRow)` ?

Comment: Remove select from this statement  Traceability.Range("D3:D100").Select = cel.Value2  as @Storax mentioned.

Comment: @VincentG yes, its E10:E

Comment: @Storax: Yes Traceability is my worksheet name. After removing (.select) as you mentioned, it still shows same error as 'Object not defined'

Comment: I was asking if it's the codename?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up to finally

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim cel As Range, lRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer


    lRow = Worksheets("Delta").UsedRange.Columns(5).Rows.Count
    rw = 3
    'iterate over every cell in the UsedRange
    For Each cel In Worksheets("Delta").Range("E10:E" & lRow)
    If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then

        'if cel is not empty, copy the value to the cell
        Sheets("Traceability").Range("D" & rw).Value = cel.Value2
        rw = rw + 1
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try:
Remove:

```
Sheets("Traceability").Select
```

Change:

```
Traceability.Range("D3:D100").Select = cel.Value2
```

to

```
 Sheets("Traceability").Range("D3:D100") = cel.Value2
```

Its been a while since i had to do this, but if i remember right, selecting the worksheet does not assign it to a variable.
You've selected Traceability worksheet, then you try to do things on "Traceability" without telling it what "Traceability" is.
If that makes sense.

Comment: Edited my answer. Forgot about the select.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. As of now all the values in (cell.value2) get updated from cells D1 to D100. What I want is thecurrent value in (cell.value2) to be updated in D3, next (cell.value2) if not null in D4, next (cell.value2) if not null in D5 and so on. I hope I am clear

Comment: ok, well thats not what your code is doing. Your current code is trying to paste a single value into a range of cells.
Your code says (in english):
    For each cell on worksheet Delta in the range E10 to E(however many used rows this sheet contains), copy the cell value (if it is not empty) into the entire range of D3 to D100 on worksheet Traceability.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. Currently I found a way to update all values using a loop.